# Select the checkbox and show the selected checkbox value in a div with close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am following a tutorial, there are multiple checkboxes , when we select the check box and click on the get selected value button then the value of the selected checkboxes alerted. [this is the tutorial site][1] .Now i want to do that when someone select the checkbox then the value of the checkbox show in a div with a close option. For now we click on the get selected value button to get the selected checkbox value but i want it automatic with out the get selected value button..i mean when we check the checkbox at the same time the value show in a div. I want to apply this for my own project. When the check box checked then the value show in a div like this.[The value of the checkbox with close option [the fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/eba6Lytk/](http://jsfiddle.net/eba6Lytk/)

```
 [1]: http://www.jquerywithexample.com/2012/11/get-selected-checkbox-using-jquery.html
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why did you put 90% of the question in code markup?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eba6Lytk/    this is the fiddle of the tutorial...i want that when someone select the checkbox then the checkbox  value show in a div with the close (X) option.

Comment: So you're expecting someone to create a closable DIV and setup all the needed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. Note that this will also:

- uncheck all other boxes when a box is clicked making sure only one
  box is checked at a time
- hide the div if the box is unchecked
- uncheck the box when the div is closed

```js
$('.chkNumber').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        //uncheck all the other boxes 
        $('.chkNumber').prop('checked', false);
        //re-check this one
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
        //show the div
        $('#hiddenDiv').show();
        //update the displayed value to that of the checked box
        $('#numberDisplay').html( $(this).val() );
    }
    else{
        //clicked box was unchecked, hide the div and clear the displayed number
        $('#hiddenDiv').hide();
        $('#numberDisplay').html('');
    }
});

$('#closeBtn').click(function(){
         //div was closed, uncheck all boxes, hide the div, and clear the displayed number 
        $('.chkNumber').prop('checked', false);
        $('#hiddenDiv').hide();
        $('#numberDisplay').html('');
});
```

```css
#hiddenDiv{
    display:none;
    border:thin inset #9B8E8E;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkNumber" value="1" />One<br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkNumber" value="2" />Two<br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkNumber" value="3" />Three<br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkNumber" value="4" />Four<br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkNumber" value="5" />Five<br /><br />
  </div>

<div id="hiddenDiv">
    <div id="numberDisplay"></div>
    <br>
     <br>
    <input type="button" id="closeBtn" value="Close Div"/>
</div>
```